# AngularJS Jasmine test $state.current empty

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I've written a component, where the $onInit does a check on the $state in order to set some variables.

In my router config I have:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.students', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/students'
});

$stateProvider.state('app.students.active', {
    url: '/active',
    component: 'listing',
    data: {
        tab: 'active'
    }
});
```

In my component I'm doing something along the lines as:

```
const vm = this;
vm.myStateName = $state.current.name;
vm.myStateData = $state.current.data;
```

Which works fine when running the app.

However, come to testing and I've encountered an issue that I've been stuck on for ages. Here's a simplified version of what is written in my test:

```
let $state, $rootScope, componentCtrl = null;

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject((_$state_, _$rootScope_, $componentController) => {
    $state = _$state_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    componentCtrl = $componentController('listing', {
        $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
        $state: $state
    });
}));

it('Should append the current model', () => {
    $state.go('app.students.active');
    $rootScope.$digest();
    componentCtrl.$onInit();
    expect(componentCtrl.data.tab).toEqual('active');
});
```

But this never gets assigned anything.

If I try to log `$state.current` in my test, I always end up with an 'empty' type state such as `{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"params":{"#":{"value":null,"type":"hash","dynamic":true}},"abstract":true}`

After a lot of research I found I'm not the only one with this issue but no suggestions on those threads have solved my issue at all:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1627

Is it because my parent is an abstract route? If so, how do I access the nested child state?

Answer (score 0):

Try below it will surely work because it gets filled later and the browser reacts. Try to include your block with $state into a $timeout(). It's a trick to wait for the $digest cycle to be over before getting the value.

```
$timeout(function() { console.log("******",$state.current.name); },1000);
```

plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/xIpkOeaQ3XyhB5gz1SnJ?p=preview